# How can I find the files for installed programs

Tags: software-installation, files, executable

Where are the files of my installed programs located?  I would like to collect all of them in one "install" folder so that I can reinstall them any time I want, just as I can do in Windows.

Comment: Debs and Snaps already store downloaded packages in a local cache. Creating your own is not necessary; simply use the local cache already there. If you *move* the packages out of the cache, the package manager might not be able to locate them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux systems use *packages* which are managed by the system using a package manager tool like *apt*

You can get a list of all packages installed by running this command:

```
apt list --installed
```

This may list out a *lot* of packages, including libraries and stuff. You can try this command instead to list out packages you probably installed yourself:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

Then anytime you want to re-install those packages you can take the list of packages and run a command like this:

```
 sudo apt install $(cat my_packages.txt)
```

Comment: you might want to add how to end up with the my_packages.txt file.... `apt-mark showmanual >> my_packages.txt`